# how to pass elements in a list to a function in a for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to print the pressure of each city.

Instead of using the cities in the list, it is returning the pressure of a city called 'city'.

Super new to this and can't find an answer to something this specific.  thanks!!!!!!

```
import pyowm
owm = pyowm.OWM('eb68e3b0c908251771e67882d7a8ddff')

city = ["tokyo", "jakarta"]

for i in city:
    city = owm.weather_at_place('city')
    city = city.get_weather()
    print (city.get_pressure()['press'])
```

Comment: Why are you naming everything `city`?

Comment: Also, do you mean `city_weather = owm.weather_at_place(i)`?

Comment: lol, not sure what I mean, still very new to programming!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use better names and things will become clearer:

```
import pyowm
owm = pyowm.OWM('eb68e3b0c908251771e67882d7a8ddff')

cities = ["tokyo", "jakarta"]

for city in cities:
    weather = owm.weather_at_place(city).get_weather()
    print (weather.get_pressure()['press'])
```

Changes and rationales:

- Changed the list of cities from `city` to `cities`. A variable named `city` should contain a city. Not a list of them.
- Changed the iteration variable used by the `for` loop to `city` because that is what will be in the variable: the name of one city. `i` is a poor name because you'd expect it to be an index, not the item, and Python `for` loops don't work that way. See how nicely `for city in cities` expresses what is actually happening?
- Changed the call to `weather_at_place()` to use the *variable* `city` (a city from the list) rather than the constant string `"city"`, as the latter would search for a city *named City.*
- Chained the calls to `weather_at_place()` and `get_weather()` rather than using `city` to hold the value returned by the former, because the intermediate value is never used. Also eliminates the use of the variable `city` for something else that is not a city.
- Changed the variable that contains the result of `get_weather()` to `weather` from `city` because it contains the weather, not the city.

Readability is important, even (especially!) when the person reading the code is the one who wrote it. If you're getting confused *now,* writing the code for the first time, imagine how confused you'll be when you try to modify the code in six months!

Comment: Thank you, thank you!  I really appreciate the help and the code works perfectly.  I appreciate it <3

Comment: @HanleySoilsmith if this solves your problem then you should mark it correct (click the grey tick on the left on the answer to turn it green). That both rewards the answerer, and tells everyone else that this problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Hanley, I hope you don't mind I rewrote your code.

```
import pyowm
owm = pyowm.OWM('eb68e3b0c908251771e67882d7a8ddff')

cities = ["tokyo", "jakarta"]

for city in cities:
    city_weather = owm.weather_at_place(city)
    weather = city_weather.get_weather()
    print(weather.get_pressure()['press'])
```

Comment: Ah, I'm not the only one, but the slower one.

Comment: Would you be so kind to accept one of the answers (I would suggest kindall's answer, he is much more elaborate (oh, I'm so modest...)).